# Find all entries of a specific tag or attribute value in lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I am given an HTML URL, from which I need to select v arious elements, based on different tag and attribute values. I am required to use lxml as par part of my assignment.

I am quite fluent with `BeautifulSoup`.

In beautifulsoup, to achieve the same,we can use

`k = soup.findAll('tagname')`

Here `soup` is

```
  <someRandomTag>...</someRandomTag>
  <someTag>
 <tagName>entry 1</tagName>
 <tagName>entry 2</tagName>
 <tagName>entry 3</tagName>
 <tagName>entry 4</tagName>
 </someTag>
```

here all entries with tag 'tagname', is returned as a list to k. Are there any equivalent to the same in `lxml`?

I am aware of `Xpath`, like  `tags=doc.xpath('descendant::*[@attrib1="atrtribval"]')`.

But I wanted to know are there any other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also `findall`:

```
In [645]: t='''
     ...: <someTag>
     ...:  <tagName>entry 1</tagName>
     ...:  <tagName>entry 2</tagName>
     ...:  <tagName>entry 3</tagName>
     ...:  <tagName>entry 4</tagName>
     ...:  </someTag>
     ...: '''

In [646]: etree.fromstring(t)
Out[646]: <Element someTag at 0x11ff3918>

In [647]: stag=etree.fromstring(t)

In [648]: stag.findall('tagName')
Out[648]: 
[<Element tagName at 0x11ff38a0>,
 <Element tagName at 0x11ff3f80>,
 <Element tagName at 0x11ff3ad0>,
 <Element tagName at 0x11ff3da0>]
```

Comment: `lxml.etree.findall` is different from `BeautifulSoup.findall`. `lxml.etree.findall('tagName')` find only children, not descendant, nor the node itself. `lxml.etree.findall('.//tagName')` find descendant, but again does not find the node itself.